# how to disable quotes around string when passed as query in python?

Tags: python, mysql

ok

I am sending a query to my mysql server somthing like this

```
INSERT INTO accesslist (user, ip, sshid, status) VALUES ("root", "138.117.37.88", "1335", "Failed")
```

for it i wrote my query as

```
query = ('INSERT INTO %s (user, ip, sshid, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)')
data_entry = (tablename, user, ip, sshid, status)
```

but what it is doing is it is adding quotes around tablename and mysql is throwing an error for that. It is sending as

```
INSERT INTO "accesslist" (user, ip, sshid, status) VALUES ("root", "138.117.37.88", "1335", "Failed")
```

so how can i remove the quotes around my tablename?

If i put a static tablename then it is working fine.

Comment: You can try the following *notice the triple quote* `query = ("""INSERT into %s (user, ip, sshid, status) values(%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (tablename, user, ip, sshid, status))`
If that works let me know and I will post it as the answer below.

Comment: @RobertWong I tried it but it is not working same error

Comment: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''accesslist10' (user, ip, sshid, status) VALUES ('root', '218.87.111.108', '1284' at line 1

Comment: File "/home/admin/Desktop/code/newcode/src/lib/dbconnect.py", line 39, in sendQuery
    self.cursor.execute(query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 483, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: How are you inserting `data_entry` in `query`? Because doing `print query % data_entry` works for me in python 2.7.

Comment: @MuhammadTahirButt cursor.execute(query, data_entry) by mysql.connector in Python 2.6.6..   When I am printing it, it is printing correctly. Problem is when I am sending it to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems correct. Not to digress, but I recommend you to use str.format as it provides more options and support named kwargs. Besides it is a newer and recommended approach.

[Tutorial](https://pyformat.info/)